# Can I resize my images after labeling them?

Tags: object-detection, object-recognition, data-preprocessing

Is it okay if I label my images with their original size and then resize them, or should I first resize them and then label them?

I mean do I need to recalibrate my labels if I resized my images?

Comment: If resizing does not change the contents of the images, then you probably can first label them and later resize them. However, resizing can actually change the $x$ and $y$ dimensions differently and make certain objects look different (e.g. stretched) and maybe no more really recognizable. I would say that if resizing changes both dimensions by the same amount, then it should be safe to label the images first, but, to be honest, I have never really studied this issue seriously.

Comment: @nbro Thanks for the response, I will consider that.

Comment: your labels are related to x,y positions into the image? if yes, you must change the x,y in labels by the same factor you use on resize your photo.

Comment: @AliKHalili In my comment above, I assumed you're doing image classification. However, as Rogelio wrote above, it's true that, if you're trying to solve a task like image segmentation (i.e. dense classification), then you'll probably need to change the labels after resizing.